# How to produce linear motion

Tags: linear, motion

I'm planning to make an automatic door lock (sort of like in the amazing spider man but it should be an easy and simpler build. So I've tried many things for example a solenoid, But my solenoid is very weak and isn't working. Next I've tried to get gears to produce linear motion from them but I didn't get them. So please help me and please give a list of ideas and how to make them and of course their materials.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try googling "car door lock actuator" ... some are fairly inexpensive and widely available.

Answer (score 1):

Use servo motors, at least that's what done in the movie. They are power full and has a feedback for angle, means that you can control its angle using code,must be familiar with micro controllers. Good luck.